Convert String To Enum with Projections.fields in QueryDSL
I have a DTO
class UserDTO{
    private String name,
    private UserStatus staus
    //getter and setters
}

and an enum class
class UserStatus {
    ACTIVE,
    SUSPENDED
}

and in the database the status is stored as a string.
class UserEntity {
    private String name,
    private String status,
}

When I try running this code using QueryDSL:
select.from(qUser).list(Projections.fields(UserDTO,class, qUser.status.as("status")

I am keep getting: java.lang.String is not compatible with enum. With Tuple, I can loop over the result and set the fields manually. But was hoping if it is possible to achieve it with Projections.fields
